# "redefinition; different type modifier" in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, asio

I'm trying to compile some code I downloaded in visual studio.  The code was intended for msvc 6, and I imported it to VS2010. The code is for providing ASIO support for labview by compiling a DLL. see [here](http://www.lasi.arizona.edu/) for the whole code.

I get the following error when building:
"error C2373:'_pctype' : redefinition; different type modifiers."

The code snippet is as follows:

`unsigned short _Ints[ 512 ];

unsigned short  *_pctype = _Ints;`

If anyone will be referencing the package of code from the link I provided, this is from the file GenMonCIN.c

Comment: It sounds like there are two variables called _pctype in the same scope. This could compiler in an earlier versions of MSVC if the first variable was declared inside a for statement, for instance, but it's difficult to tell without the surrounding code. Rather than digging into the library you're using, listing the relevant code here would be a real help. Specifically, can you cite the function in which the error occurs?

Comment: thx for the suggestion JMcF, but there are no other occurrences. If you need further information, I did actually site the function in which this error occurs in my original post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is trying to tell you that `_pctype` was already defined somewhere else.

It [appears](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53c3bwd6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that `_pctype` is an identifier used by Visual Studio since at least version 2005.

> `_pctype`, `_pwctype`, `_wctype`, `_mbctype`, `_mbcasemap`
>
> These global variables contain information used by the character classification functions. They are for internal use only.

Please [never pick names with a leading underscore at namespace scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), they are reserved for the implementation. The person who wrote the library obviously didn't know that, and now you're screwed.

Comment: okay... thx, i can see the problem in that case. but why am I screwed, can't I just rename the variable to something else? strangely enough, "_pctype" doesn't appear in the project any where else except for at this declaration. I'm not sure why the authors' have made this declaration to be honest, the only other information I can supply is that after the "_Ints" declaration, this is commented"// Sound buffer code makes ref to these externals, but doesn't supply"